# Using HP Fortify and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, fortify

I'm having this issue... after successfuly building an iOS 6.0 (Xcode 4.5) project separately using xcodebuild, the sourceanalyzer first reports missing .nst files for couple classes including stdarg.h and similar. Seems like sourceanalyzer cannot see the iPhone SDK's Header Search Paths. However Fortify seems so rare, that I haven't spotted any answer yet, especially regards to compatibility with various Xcode versions, etc. Anyone?

```
$ sourceanalyzer -b Forty xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos6.1
```

Output:

```
Build settings from command line:
SDKROOT = iphoneos6.1

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET fortifyTest OF PROJECT fortifyTest WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

ProcessPCH     /var/folders/yp/2l8w2hpd08199zstwqnxnvs80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/fortifyTest-Prefix-gfjvmaafdrnknjehmxvutbaqdpny/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch.pth fortifyTest/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Applications/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.70/bin"
/Users/sychram/.fortify/sca5.14/build/Forty/build717537620538182813/clang -x objective-c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -iquote /Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/fortifyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/fortifyTest.build/fortifyTest-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/fortifyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/fortifyTest.build/fortifyTest-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/fortifyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/fortifyTest.build/fortifyTest-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/fortifyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/fortifyTest.build/fortifyTest-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/fortifyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/fortifyTest.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/fortifyTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/fortifyTest.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/build/Debug-iphoneos --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/yp/2l8w2hpd08199zstwqnxnvs80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/fortifyTest-Prefix-gfjvmaafdrnknjehmxvutbaqdpny/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/fortifyTest/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/yp/2l8w2hpd08199zstwqnxnvs80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/fortifyTest-Prefix-gfjvmaafdrnknjehmxvutbaqdpny/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/yp/2l8w2hpd08199zstwqnxnvs80000gp/C/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/fortifyTest-Prefix-gfjvmaafdrnknjehmxvutbaqdpny/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch.d
[error]: Translator execution failed.  Please consult the Troubleshooting section of the    User Manual. 
Translator returned status 1:

In file included from /Users/sychram/Repositories/fortifyTest/fortifyTest/fortifyTest-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:78:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:35:10: fatal error: 'i386/types.h' file not found
#include "i386/types.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how exactly this software works? Do I have to install this software on my mac or have to upload my source code to Fortify web-portal. I am looking for Fortify static code analyzer for iOS application scanning.

Comment: Fortify is an application written in Java, that can be run on Linux/Mac/Windows. It requires and uses underlying build-system (based on ant, maven, cmake, xcode etc) static code analyzer. There is also a service called HP Fortify 360 that is SaaS where you upload your code to 3rd party (Fortify) web portal. Fortify has been sold by HP so the future of it is kind of unclear. You can also try Checkmarx (also SaaS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK only xcode versions 4.1, 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.3 are supported by fortify in the latest release 3.7.

Comment: Neither the prefix header, neither system frameworks included in the project (UIKit, Security...) are actually copied to the /ObjC/ folder.

Comment: +1 to greencrizz, 4.3.3 fails, 4.3.0 works. It will require bigger hammer and some yelling both at Apple and HP. Fortify 3.7 is great for analyzing 2 years old projects, not apps that should be released in the future.

Comment: same here, but we have openend a enhancement request to push this. and yes, you´re right regarding scanning old projects.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is support for xcode 4.6 with SCA version 4.02. But I am still waiting for xcode 5.x to support by fortify, that I will be able to scan apps based on iOS7. since february apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7.

Comment: There is already Fortify Static Code Analyzer 6.00.0096 that supports both Xcode 5 and iOS 7 projects (Obj-C 2.0 syntax, prefixes, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, then I´ll have to re-check this on my Mac. I thought that there was a warning when I issued the sourceanalyzer command.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how exactly this software works? Do I have to install this software on my mac or have to upload my source code to Fortify web-portal. I am looking for Fortify static code analyzer for iOS application scanning.